# Selenium - Maven/TestNG: How to add "testng.xml" and log4j2.xml path in pom.xml so executable .jar file can be executed on other machine as well?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jar, testng

I am working with Maven/TestNG/Log4j2.

Our aim is to create an executable .jar file which will run testng.xml via pom.xml file.

So right now, I am able to create an executable .jar file and able to run it successfully on my machine as well. But when I try to run same .jar file on another machine then It's throwing an "Filenotfoundexception" as it is trying to access testng.xml and log4j2.xml with my local path.

Also, executable .Jar file has testng.xml and log4j2.xml file in it's root level only.

Here is my project structure:

[image: project]

I have used "maven assembly, surefire, compiler plugins" and resources tag for .xml files.

This is how my build looks like:

```
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
 <plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
     <configuration>
      <release>10</release>
     </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>           
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>make-assembly</id>
    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
    <!-- get all project dependencies -->
       <descriptorRefs>                          
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>                         
       </descriptorRefs>                         
        <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->                         
       <archive>
       <manifest>                                
        <mainClass>test.FirstTest</mainClass>                            
       </manifest>
       </archive>
     </configuration>
    </execution>
   </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>               
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
      <configuration>
       <suiteXmlFiles>                   
      <suiteXmlFile>.//src/main/java/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
       </suiteXmlFiles>
      </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 <resources>
  <resource>                 
   <directory>src/main/java/resources</directory>
    <includes>
     <include>*.xml</include>
    </includes>
   </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

And this is how my testNG main method looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 TestNG testng = new TestNG();
 List<String> suites = Lists.newArrayList();
 suites.add(".//src/main/java/resources/testng.xml");
 testng.setTestSuites(suites);
 testng.run();
}
```

We are aiming to create an executable .jar file bundled with testng.xml and log4j2.xml. So we can share it with other teams as well.

Please let me know if you need any more info.

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple to include and exclude the files in the build process. I provide below the code snippet for you understand.

```
<build>
        <resources>
          <resource>
            <directory>src/resources</directory>
<!-- To include the files -->
             <includes>
                 <include>**/*.properties</include>
                 <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
<!-- To exclude -->
            <excludes>
              <exclude>**/*.jpeg</exclude>
              <exclude>**/*.gif</exclude>
            </excludes>
          </resource>
    </resources>
.....
.....
</build>
```

To create a a runnable jar file, refer below the very simple and small project in github.

https://github.com/debjava/runnableJar

Comment: If you look at my pom.xml, I have used same thing. But it's not working on another machine using runnable .jar file